# How to use tow operators in query an SQLite query statement?

Tags: android-sqlite

I am querying from SQLite Database where I need to combine the two operators "AND" and "OR" in a single query, using below code. The cursor does not return data. How can I use tow operators in query statement?

```
    String[] selectedTopics = getSelectedTopics();
    String[] selectedArgs = new String[selectedTopics.length + 3];

    String selection = "(" + COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_DIFFICULTY + " = ? AND " 
        +   COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_IS_SELECTED + " = ? AND "  
        +   COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_IS_REJECTED + " = ? ) AND (";
    for (int i = 0; i < (selectedTopics.length); i++) {
        if (i != (selectedTopics.length - 1)) {
            selection += "topic = ? OR ";
        } else {
            selection += "topic = ? ) ";
        }
    }

    selectedArgs[0] = String.valueOf(difficulty);
    selectedArgs[1] = "0";
    selectedArgs[2] = "0";
    int k = 0;
    for (int j = 3; j < selectedArgs.length; j++) {
        selectedArgs[j] = selectedTopics[k];
        k++;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "getNewWordsToLearn: selection = " + selection);
    Log.i(TAG, "getNewWordsToLearn: selectionsArgs = " + 
           Arrays.toString(selectedArgs));

   Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_NAME_FOREIGN_WORDS,null, selection, 
      selectedArgs, null, null, null);
```

The log shows :-

```
2019-06-15 14:25:43.634 15564-15590/com.marzoq.vocabuilder I/DBQueries: getNewWordsToLearn: selection = (difficulty = ? AND isSelected = ? AND isRejected = ? ) AND (topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? )     
2019-06-15 14:25:43.634 15564-15590/com.marzoq.vocabuilder I/DBQueries: getNewWordsToLearn: selectionsArgs = [1, 0, 0, Appearance, Eating out, Environment, Food, Health, Home, Leisure, People, Politics, Reference, Services, Sports, Study, Transport, Work]
2019-06-15 14:25:43.641 15564-15590/com.marzoq.vocabuilder I/TestRunner: failed: getNewWordsToLearn(com.marzoq.vocabuilder.DBQueriesTest)
```

"I expect that c.getCount > 0, but this never happen using the above query"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is a misunderstanding of logic. That is assuming data in the database such as (as per the example run below) :-

1. `Difficulty = 1, IsRejected = 0, IsSlected 0, Topic = "People"`
2. `Difficulty = 1, IsRejected = 0, IsSlected 0, Topic = "Leisure"`
3. `Difficulty = 1, IsRejected = 0, IsSlected 0, Topic = "Not a Listed Topic"`
4. `Difficulty = 1, IsRejected = 1, IsSlected 0, Topic = "People"`
5. `Difficulty = 1, IsRejected = 0, IsSlected 1, Topic = "People"`
6. `Difficulty = 1, IsRejected = 1, IsSlected 1, Topic = "People"`
7. `Difficulty = 2, IsRejected = 0, IsSlected 0, Topic = "People"`

Along with the list of selected topics being :-

- Appearance, Eating out, Environment, Food, Health, Home, Leisure, People, Politics, Reference, Services, Sports, Study, Transport, Work

Then only 1 and 2 would be **SELECT**ed as :-

- Difficulty is 1
- AND IsRejected is 0
- AND IsSelected is 0
- AND the topics **People**/**Leisure** are in the list of selected topics

3-7 Will not be extracted as :-

- 3. **Not a Listed Topic** is not a topic in the list, thus the `AND (Topic = ? OR ......)` is false (not true)
- 4. **IsRejected** is not 0 so the `AND isRejected` is false so the 3 AND's in the parenthesis is false and therefore the overall result is false.
- 5. **IsSelected** is no 0 (so same result as such as 4)
- 6. Both **IsRejected** and **IsSelected** are false (hence same result as 4)
- 7. Difficulty is not 1 (aagain same result as 4).

Basically when using AND both side of the expression must be TRUE for the expression to be TRUE.

The above was testing using a slightly amended version of your code as per :-

```
public void doit(int difficulty, String[] topicsSelected) {

    String TAG = "DBQueries";
    String[] selectedTopics = topicsSelected; //<<<<<<<<<< get the topics from parameter passed
    String[] selectedArgs = new String[selectedTopics.length + 3];

    String selection = "(" + COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_DIFFICULTY + " = ? AND "
            + COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_IS_SELECTED + " = ? AND "
            + COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_IS_REJECTED + " = ? ) AND (";
    for (
            int i = 0; i < (selectedTopics.length); i++) {
        if (i != (selectedTopics.length - 1)) {
            selection += "topic = ? OR ";
        } else {
            selection += "topic = ? ) ";
        }
    }

    selectedArgs[0] = String.valueOf(difficulty);
    selectedArgs[1] = "0";
    selectedArgs[2] = "0";
    int k = 0;
    for (
            int j = 3;
            j < selectedArgs.length; j++) {
        selectedArgs[j] = selectedTopics[k];
        k++;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "getNewWordsToLearn: selection = " + selection);
    Log.i(TAG, "getNewWordsToLearn: selectionsArgs = " +
            Arrays.toString(selectedArgs));

    Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_NAME_FOREIGN_WORDS, null, selection,
            selectedArgs, null, null, null);
    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED CODE
    Log.i(TAG,"Number of rows extracted is " + String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Extracted row is:-  Topic is " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_TOPIC))   );
    }
}
```

- See comments for changes

Along with the following method (also in the Database Helper Class) to allow some testing data to be added :-

```
public long add(int difficulty, boolean rejected, boolean selected, String topic) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_DIFFICULTY,difficulty);
    cv.put(COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_IS_REJECTED,rejected);
    cv.put(COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_IS_SELECTED,selected);
    cv.put(COLUMN_FOREIGN_WORDS_TOPIC,topic);
    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME_FOREIGN_WORDS,null,cv);
}
```

The following was then used in an Activity to add some data and then call your code (the **doit** method) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper002 mDBHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper002(this);
        String[] selectedtopics = new String[]{"Appearance", "Eating out", "Environment", "Food", "Health, Home", "Leisure", "People", "Politics", "Reference", "Services", "Sports", "Study", "Transport", "Work"};
        mDBHelper.add(1,false,false,"People");
        mDBHelper.add(1,false,false,"Leisure");
        mDBHelper.add(1,false,false,"Not a Listed Topic"); // Not Extracted as Not a Listed Topic is not one of the selected topics
        mDBHelper.add(1,true,false,"People"); //Not extracted as rejected is true (not 0) otherwise it would be selected
        mDBHelper.add(1,false,true,"People"); //Not extracted as selected is true (not 0) otherwise it would be selected
        mDBHelper.add(1,true,true,"People"); //Not extracted as rejected is true (not 0) and because selected is true
        mDBHelper.add(2,false,false,"People"); //Not Extracted as difficulty is not 1 otherwise is would be selected
        mDBHelper.doit(1,selectedtopics);
    }
}
```

The results being :-

```
06-16 07:07:17.932 32648-32648/? I/DBQueries: getNewWordsToLearn: selection = (diff = ? AND selected = ? AND rejected = ? ) AND (topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? OR topic = ? ) 
06-16 07:07:17.932 32648-32648/? I/DBQueries: getNewWordsToLearn: selectionsArgs = [1, 0, 0, Appearance, Eating out, Environment, Food, Health, Home, Leisure, People, Politics, Reference, Services, Sports, Study, Transport, Work]
06-16 07:07:17.932 32648-32648/? I/DBQueries: Number of rows extracted is 2
06-16 07:07:17.932 32648-32648/? I/DBQueries: Extracted row is:-  Topic is People
06-16 07:07:17.932 32648-32648/? I/DBQueries: Extracted row is:-  Topic is Leisure
```